# .htaccess for language detection

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to work with virtual url for handling the language with folder or subfolder like

```
www.example.com/en/xxx/
OR www.example.com/xxx/en
OR www.example.com/xxx/xxx/en
```

And all give the same `?lang=en`

Its possible ?

Thanks you

I tested this for subdomaine

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]

# language
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?ln=%1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With PHP its work

```
$url = explode('/', $_GET['a']);
if(in_array('fr', $url)) {
$language = 'fr';
}
elseif(in_array('it', $url)) {
$language = 'it';
}
else {
$language = 'en';
}
```

Comment: What have tried so far?  I would presume part of the solution depends on how you are routing your requests.

Comment: I edit my post, but its work for subdomaine

Comment: Which part is not working in your .htaccess?

Comment: No its work for `en.example.com` or `example.com/en` but not work for `example.com/xxx/en` i need to detect if `/en/` existe and change that to ?`lang=en`

Comment: are any of these real directories? What is the full URL it's supposed to rewrite to? So you want `example.com/xxx/en` to go to `http://example.com/?lang=en` ?

Comment: Yes for `example.com/xxx/en` i need `index.php?lang=en&a=xxx` (i edit my post its work with php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for this specific example.

> example.com/xxx/en i need index.php?lang=en&a=xxx

You can use a rule like this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/en/?$ /index.php?lang=en&a=$1 [L,QSA]
```